# Why the [disabled] in some cases is true in Angular Reactive form?

Tags: angular

I have made a reactive form with input which accepts only 12 digits `[mask]="000000000000"`  . When I locally check input i.e 111111111111 `[disabled]` works fine and the button is enabled. After deploying for production for some reason , some users have issue with this button , they put correct data (i.e 12 digits) but button is always `disabled`. When I check on prod everything works fine. May be the reason is unsupported `[mask]` or `[Validators]` in some browsers , doesn't it ?

**ts**

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
 iin: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
 verify_code: new FormControl('')
});
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="authorization__form">
      <div class="profile-inputs">
        <div class="profile-inputs__box">
          <div
            i18n="Проверка ИИН | поле @@modal.iin"
            class="profile-inputs__name"
          >
            ИИН
          </div>
          <input
            mask="000000000000"
            class="input"
            name="iin"
            mask="000000000000"
            formControlName="iin"
            [class.border-danger]="form.touched && form.controls.iin.errors"
            type="text"
            required
          />...


<button
    *ngIf="!smsSent"
    [disabled]="form.invalid"
    i18n="Проверка ИИН | поле @@modal.getSmsCode"
    class="reg__button button-blue"
    (click)="getSms()"
  >
    Get Sms
  </button>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a custom validator for length instead of using mask. It might be the case not all the versions of browser support this.

Comment: So the title is simply invalid as form is not "always" invalid but only in some cases.

Comment: @Antoniossss changed title

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I didn't know that mask is not supported in some browsers so I will try to write my own validator

Comment: Mask is some sort of 3rd party solution (ngx-mask??) so it might contains some browser related bugs. Using custom validator or just simple regex pattern validator should work everywhere.

Comment: Yes , i'm using ngx mask in my project

Comment: I have read about ngx-mask and some says that trouble is polyfills , I have added ```import 'core-js/modules/es.array.includes';``` I will check if this code solves my issue